# Best practice for nesting ContentViews into ContentPage as Xamarin architecture

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am have an app that basically loads a bunch of ContentViews into the home ContentPage. I THINK there is a problem here because all of the viewmodels would essentially need to been initialized every time we load the home page. I am wondering if it is worth my time to ditch the below code and convert the views from ContentView's to ContentPage's and just do Navigation.PushAsync(new View1()); instead. Sorry I know this is alot of example code but I would really like to get a clear picture of best practice.

```
My Home.xaml

    <Grid x:Name="ContentBody" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <local:View1 Grid.Row="0" x:Name="View1" IsVisible="{Binding View1IsVisible}" BindingContext="{Binding View1ViewModel}" />
    <local:View2 Grid.Row="0" x:Name="View2" IsVisible="{Binding View2IsVisible}" BindingContext="{Binding View2ViewModel}" />
    <local:View3 Grid.Row="0" x:Name="View3" IsVisible="{Binding View3IsVisible}" BindingContext="{Binding View3ViewModel}" />
    <local:View4 Grid.Row="0" x:Name="View4" IsVisible="{Binding View4IsVisible}" BindingContext="{Binding View4ViewModel}" />
    <local:View5 Grid.Row="0" x:Name="View5" IsVisible="{Binding View5IsVisible}" BindingContext="{Binding View5ViewModel}" />
    <local:View6 Grid.Row="0" x:Name="View6" IsVisible="{Binding View6IsVisible}" BindingContext="{Binding View6ViewModel}" />
    <local:DrawerView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="DrawerView" IsVisible="{Binding DrawerViewIsVisible}" />

</Grid>

Then In my HomeViewModel...

    private readonly View1ViewModel _view1ViewModel = new View1ViewModel();
    public View1ViewModel View1ViewModel { get { return _view1ViewModel; } }
    private readonly View2ViewModel _view2ViewModel = new View2ViewModel();
    public View2ViewModel View2ViewModel { get { return _view2ViewModel; } }
    private readonly View3ViewModel _view3ViewModel = new View3ViewModel();
    public View3ViewModel View3ViewModel { get { return _view3ViewModel; } }
    private readonly View4ViewModel _view4ViewModel = new View4ViewModel();
    public View4ViewModel View4ViewModel { get { return _view4ViewModel; } }
    private readonly View5ViewModel _view5ViewModel = new View5ViewModel();
    public View5ViewModel View5ViewModel { get { return _view5ViewModel; } }
    private readonly View6ViewModel _view6ViewModel = new View6ViewModel();
    public View6ViewModel View6ViewModel { get { return _view6ViewModel; } }
///////////////////Some Visibility Properties...//////////////////////
```

```html
///////////////////Some Visibility Properties...//////////////////////
private bool _view1IsVisible;
public bool View1IsVisible
{
    get { return _view1IsVisible; }
    set { _view1IsVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged("View1IsVisible"); }
}

private bool _view2IsVisible;
public bool View2IsVisible
{
    get { return _view2IsVisible; }
    set { _view2IsVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged("View2IsVisible"); }
}

private bool _view3IsVisible;
public bool View3IsVisible
{
    get { return _view3IsVisible; }
    set { _view3IsVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged("View3IsVisible"); }
}

private bool _view4IsVisible;
public bool View4IsVisible
{
    get { return _view4IsVisible; }
    set { _view4IsVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged("View4IsVisible"); }
}

private bool _view5IsVisible;
public bool View5IsVisible
{
    get { return _view5IsVisible; }
    set { _view5IsVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged("View5IsVisible"); }
}

private bool _view6IsVisible;
public bool View6IsVisible
{
    get { return _view6IsVisible; }
    set { _view6IsVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged("View6IsVisible"); }
}

/////And then this is more or less a method to show the view/////////////

private void ShowView(ViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    HideAllViews();
    switch(e.SelectedView){
     case ViewType.View1:
      View1IsVisible = true
      break;
     case ViewType.View2:
      View2IsVisible = true
      break;
     case ViewType.View3:
      View3IsVisible = true
      break;
     case ViewType.View4:
      View4IsVisible = true
      break;
     case ViewType.View5:
      View5IsVisible = true
      break;
     case ViewType.View6:
      View6IsVisible = true
      break;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me if this approach is fine? as using this approach everytime I add a new page I will need to add a view to the Homepage view and the viewModel & IsVisible properties to the Homepage ViewModel..

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on this. I think a better approach would be to just seperate the ContentViews from the HomePage and when I Navigate to one of these views I would just PushAsync. I have seen supporting documentation online where some people are taking the above approach, I am just trying to ask the experts what they think when they see this code.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve that you couldn't do with multiple ContentPages?  Is each ContentView really that distinct from the others?

Comment: The wholw app works as above I am jist wondering if there is a potential issue since every view model in the app is loaded on the homepage view

Comment: I inherited this code and I am wondering if it is normal to have have all the viwws loaded onto your main view like this

Comment: Frankly, it seems like a weird way to do things.  If you're really stuck with this approach, I wouldn't put all the ContentViews in the XAML, instead I would just instantiate and display them as needed, which should be less memory intensive.

Comment: I was kinda leaning that direction to. I think it would be better to change all of the views to ContentPages and just PushAsync when needed, instead of having all these PartialViews. I appreciate you taking a look as t this I wasbt sure of this was intentionally done this was as part of some best practice

Comment: This would be an ok practice for hiding/showing view's on the same content page, but if each view model is for a separate page in the app then you should go with your plan above

Comment: That is good advice, I am not sure why it was originally developed like this. It seems like an odd way to do things so I assumed it was intentional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking w/ a member of the Xamarin team I've been told to remove all the views from this homeview page, bind the perspective view models in their own code behinds, and from there I can navigation using Navigation.PushAsync(new View1());

Tutorial: 
https://github.com/XamarinUniversity/XAM290

Documentaiton: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/